# Bind/unbind scroll event after fancybox closes

Tags: jquery, scroll, fancybox

I have a scroll event which fixes my header on top of the page. I've managed to unbind that event when fancybox opens, but I can't get that scrollable header to work once I close fancybox. Any ideas?

```
    // Scrollable header
      var bar = $('.scrollable');
      $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if($(this).scrollTop() > 51) {
            bar.css({"position":"fixed"});
            bar.css({"top":"-51px"});
          } else {
            bar.css({"position":"absolute"});
            bar.css({"top":"0"});
          }
        });
      });
```

And this is the fancybox part:

```
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({ 
        'fitToView': false, 
        'afterClose' : function() {
          $(window).bind("scroll");
          $('.inner').css({"position":"static"});
        }
      });

      $('.fancybox').click(function(){
        $(window).unbind("scroll");
        $('.inner').css({"position":"fixed"});
      });
```